# Como insertar de un array a MYSQL desde PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero insertar en una tabla, orden_productos, el producto que me solicitaron más la cantidad solicitada pero como pueden ser varios productos los metí en un array e igual con las cantidades pero cuando los inserta en la base de dato en vez de crearme un registro con id del item y la cantidad, crea un registro por cada cantidad y no por producto.

```
    <?php
#capturar datos
$estado=$_POST['estado'];
$departamento=$_POST['dep'];
$productos=$_POST['productos'];
$cantidades=$_POST['cantidad'];
include_once('conexion.php');
$con=conexion();
#consulta
$sql="INSERT INTO `requisiciones`.`orden` (`estado`, `departamento`) VALUES('$estado','$departamento')";
$query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$idorden = mysqli_insert_id($con);
echo $idorden;
foreach ($productos as $idproduc){
foreach($cantidades as $cantidad){
$sql3="INSERT INTO orden_productos (IDORDEN, IDPRODUCTO, CANTIDAD) VALUES ($idorden, $idproduc,'$cantidad')";
$query3=mysqli_query($con,$sql3);
}
}
```

Logro insertar los datos, el id de la orden y el id del producto pero se insertan los productos dos veces, es decir se repite por cada cantidad que recibo.

Comment: todo va a depender la forma que estes armando el array que recibe por post el php. Si puedes edita y coloca el javascript o en su defecto el console.log del o los arrays que envias

Comment: Creo que puedes usar array_values() para tomar los valores de los array e ir iterando cada posición, antes de ellos validar que lo que se recibio sea un array y que ambos array tengan la misma longitud, así podrías evitar doble foreach si no estoy mal

Comment: ¿Estás enviando tus datos por Ajax o por Fetch o directamente? ¿Usas un formulario? Si es así, ¿cómo has declarados las etiqueta `name` de los input que usas para recoger los datos? Lo más simple sería mandar tus datos ya estructurados desde el cliente, algo como: `array(array('estado'=>1, 'producto'=>'P1'), array('estado'=>2, 'producto'=>'P2'), array('estado'=>3, 'producto'=>'P3'))`y luego iterar sobre ese array único. Organizar los datos así desde el cliente no es tan complicado si usaras Ajax o la API Fetch de Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo lo haría de esta manera, solo te dejo tu ejemplo a mi apegado a lo que Yo haría, espero te sirva

```
//Conexión a base de datos
include_once('conexion.php');
$conexion = conexion();

// Capturar de datos
$estado = $_POST['estado'];
$departamento = $_POST['dep'];

$productos = $_POST['productos'];
$cantidades = $_POST['cantidad'];

if(!is_array($productos)) {
    echo 'No es array';
    return; 
}

if(!is_array($cantidades)) {
    echo 'No es array';
    return; 
}

//Aquí puedes hacer una validación de array longitud
//$productos.lenght === $productos.length

// Consulta a base de datos, recuerda usar commits PHP para evitar que se inserten registros "falsos"
$sql = "INSERT INTO requisiciones.orden ('estado', 'departamento') VALUES ($estado, $departamento)";
$query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

$idorden = mysqli_insert_id($con);

$arrayProductos = array_values($productos);
$arraycantidades = array_values($cantidades);

// Recorres cada posición de productos insertas y a la vez insertar cada posición de cantidades
foreach ($arrayProductos as $key => $valorProductos) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO orden_productos (IDORDEN, IDPRODUCTO, CANTIDAD) VALUES ($idorden, $valorProductos, $arraycantidades[$key])";
    $query = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
}
```

Comment: Perfecto justamente eso me sirvio, ya vi que me estaba complicando realmente muchas gracias minor

Comment: Se me olvido agregar la parte de commit() y rollback() por si no inserta en la primera tabla, no se inserta nada en la segunda, evitas registros fantasma ¡De nada!